# How to use just a class library of ZEND FRAMEWORK?

Tags: zend-framework

i just want to use MAIL class of ZEND FRAMEWORK

What file i have to include in my script?

thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
include '/path/to/Zend/lib/Zend/Mail.php'
$zendMail = new Zend_Mail();
```

Comment: Might need some other ones too ;) But it's best practice to set include path to Zend's library folder. Then the files are included automatically ;)

Comment: I recently asked similar question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314960/  - but you should keep the whole **Zend** library directory and include mail class, you also should add library path to __include_path__ as Tomas mentioned.